# Error when building sphinx documentation in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, python-sphinx

I am trying to build sphinx documentation using an Azure pipeline, but I am running into an issue I do not understand.

My Python package's root folder contains a docs/ directory with all of the sphinx stuff, just in the same way it is automatically generated. In a docker container, I can run

```
make -C docs/ html
```

which works fine with the output

```
make: Entering directory '/workspaces/PACKAGE/docs'
Running Sphinx v4.5.0
making output directory... done
WARNING: html_static_path entry '_static' does not exist
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 3 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 3 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
generating indices... genindex done
writing additional pages... search done
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warning.

The HTML pages are in build/html.
make: Leaving directory '/workspaces/PACKAGE/docs'
```

However, in the Azure pipeline I perform a job containing the same script

```
- job: build_doc
  displayName: Build documentation
  steps:
  - script: sudo pip install .[dev,doc]
    displayName: Install dependencies

  - script: make -C docs/ html
    displayName: Build documentation
```

which fails when running the pipeline, with the output

```
make: Entering directory '/home/vsts/work/1/s/docs'
Running Sphinx v4.5.0
making output directory... done
WARNING: html_static_path entry '_static' does not exist

Exception occurred:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 163, in __init__
    self.searchpath = list(searchpath)
TypeError: 'PosixPath' object is not iterable
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-bbvaofy6.log, if you want to report the 
issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided 
next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. 
Thanks!
make: *** [Makefile:20: html] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/vsts/work/1/s/docs'
##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
```

I have made sure to rebuild the container, so I don't see why there would be any missing dependencies that mess with the build process. Any ideas of what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the issue.

Some Sphinx extensions only work with Python versions < 3.10, and in my local Docker container I had specified the correct version. However, I had failed to specify a Python version for the Azure pipeline, resulting in the default version (in this case 3.10).